# Inconsistent DateTime conversion behaviour in .NET Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, sharepoint

## Problem

I've a Windows app syncs with the Server using SharePoint hosted Web Services.
When the app syncs to the server using LAN (goes through an internal Proxy server) all the DateTime formats are in dd/MM/yyyy format (which is how it is intended to be)
However, when the app syncs over 4G,all DateTime formats are in MM/dd/yyyy format.
This happens for all data inbound and outbound.

### Server

Windows Server 2012 with SharePoint 2013 hosting SOAP services
Region: Singapore
Format: English (Singapore)

### Client

Windows 10 tablet app
Region: Singapore
Format: English (Singapore)

**Other information:**
 1. It is the same tablet being used on both WiFi and 4G, so we can rule
    out 2 tablets having different regional settings. 
 2. I've verified that the Windows 10 app passes the formats correctly and it is the server that behaves differently over WiFi and 4G. 
3. I beleive  that the issue is caused by .NET itself and not because of SharePoint. However, I don't want to rule it out as I'm not sure of the actual cause. Please comment if you require any further information if you feel that it is caused because of SharePoint

## Snippets:

I've skipped the using statements and SPWeb statements in the snippet to keep it simple. And the LastModifiedTime field in the SPList of type DateTime and not single line text.

#### Model

```
public class Record
{
    public string ID {get; set}
    public string ModifiedDateTime {get; set;} //Don't ask why it is not a DateTime object. It was too late by the time I took over
}
```

#### Web Service

```
public class WebService : IWebService
{
    public List<Record> GetUpdates(string lastModifiedTime)
    {
        SPQuery query= QueryBuilder.GetUpdateQuery(lastModifiedDateTime);
        SPList spRecordList = spWeb.Lists["Record"];
        SPListItemCollection results = spRecordList.GetItems(query);
        List<Record> records = new List<Record>();
        foreach(SPListItem spRecord in results)
        {
            Record record = new Record();
            record.ID = spRecord.ID.ToString();
            record.ModifiedDateTime = Convert.ToString(spRecord["LastModifiedTime"]);
            //1 June 2015 would return as 01/06/2015 in WiFi but 06/01/2015 on 4G

            records.Add(record);
        } 
        return records;
    }

    public Record CreateOrUpdateRecord(Record record)
    {
        SPListItem spRecord = null;
        SPList spRecordList = spWeb.Lists["Record"];
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(record.ID))
        {
            spRecord = spRecordList.AddItem();
            record.ID = spRecord.ID.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            spRecord = spRecordList.GetItemByID(record.ID);
        }

        DateTime modified = Convert.ToDateTime(record.Modified);
        spRecord["LastModifiedTime"] = modified;

        /*
            Say ModifiedDateTime is 1 June 2015.
            Then on WiFi, modified = 01/06/2015
            On 4G, modified = 06/01/2015
        */

        return record;

    }
}
```

Now, I've fixed the problem by using format strings when converting between string and DateTime and vice-versa. So more or less, I've got it working for now.

So my question here is, what is the reason behind this behaviour? If possible, please cite links to documentation or references to any other sources that explain this behaviour

Is it possible that the server infers the culture info from the request header? I've always thought that the DateTime.Parse()/Convert.ToDateTime() always got the defaults from the regional settings of the machine it runs on.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a `DateTime` does not have *any* implicit format. It just have date and time values. Format concept only applies when you get it *textual* (string) representation. I *strongly* suggest to change this data type from `string` to `DateTime` if you *can* that returns by web service.

> I've verified that the Windows 10 app passes the formats correctly and
>   it is the server that behaves differently over WiFi and 4G

There is no such a thing. Parsing string to DateTime or vice versa does *not* depends on how you connected to internet. It is all about culture settings.

Since you use it as;

```
DateTime modified = Convert.ToDateTime(record.Modified);
```

This code will use `CurrentCulture` settings *by default* where it's located. Since you said;

> It is the same tablet being used on both WiFi and 4G, **so we can rule
>   out 2 tablets having different regional settings**

One regional settings parse your string as a 6 January and the other settings parse your string as 1 June. That's *too* normal. Looks like one setting uses `dd/MM/yyyy` format and the other one uses `MM/dd/yyyy`.

As a solution, you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` method to specify *exact* culture that matches with your string. Or you can equalize regional settings on both tablet.

For example;

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("01/06/2015", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

will parse as 1 June 2015 but

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("01/06/2015", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

will parse as 6 January 2015.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your answer was exactly what I thought too. If the Convert.ToDateTime does use the server's current culture, then why would it behave in 2 different ways for the above scenarios? As I said, I've already applied the fix that you had mentioned on code. But I'm rather interested in knowing the reason behind this behaviour.

Comment: @Sugesh If you don't provide any culture for all `DateTime` parsing methods (include `Convert.ToDateTime`), they use `CurrentCulture` settings by default. Clearly one settings parse your string as `1 June 2015` but the other one is parsing as `6 January 2015`. In my `DateTime.ParseExact` example, I supplied a format that matches exactly on the string. In first one, I used `dd/MM/yyyy` format and said; "`01` should be parsed as day and `06` should be parsed as month part" and used the `MM/dd/yyyy` format which is clearly means opposite. That's why they returns different results.

Comment: Both of us are in the same page that the method that I initially used the CurrentCulture. Maybe my question wasn't clear. What could be the reason that the CurrentCulture was different for the two scenarios? It is the same server, same method and I would expect that both calls have the same result because it is the same server and no regional settings have been changed between the two calls. And it consistently happens for the WiFi/4G scenario that I mentioned. I've tested it multiple times and it is the same every time.

Comment: @Sugesh But you said: `..so we can rule out 2 tablets having different regional settings` in your question. That makes your `CurrentCulture` settings differently in your both tablets. And that's why you get different results. Just try to set them equal and see the difference.

Comment: Maybe my choice of words wasn't clear. It is the same tablet I used for both scenarios. First call over WiFi and the second call over 4G. I meant that we can exclude the possibility that the tablets have different cultures from possible factors.